# insert value in input->value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how is insert value data `success: function(data)...` in into tag input->value `<input type="text" name="number" id="number" value="">` with jQuery?

Example: [jsfiddle - my code](http://jsfiddle.net/JaYkw/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#number').val("value = " + $('#number').val().replace("placeholder", data));
}
```

Comment: i want insert in value="" -> value="data"

Comment: thanks, if input have placeholder, how remove placeholder and insert data in `value=""`?

Answer (score 12):

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#number').val(data);
}
```

Comment: i want insert in value="" -> value="data"

Comment: If you mean set the value to "data", then it would be `$('#number').val('data')` instead.